# Remove HTML from dom if mobile browser with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mobile

Is this possible? I mean, I know you can use `display: none;` with `media queries`, but that does not prevent the nodes to be loaded, which is resource intensive. I don't want to hide them, I want to remove them.

That's why I used this:

```
function removeit() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
     $('html').remove('aside');
    }
}
```

And put it in the header, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I tried using it with `document ready function`, but still not working on my `iPhone`. I keep seeing the `aside sidebar`.

PS 2: jQuery is loaded in the header, I have tried to put this snippet beneath the jQuery call.

Comment: They still get loaded before they get removed (you can't remove it before it's loaded), so you gain nothing.

Comment: Ah, that I did not think of... in that case, hiding and removing is the same?

Comment: It might differ when there are some images or other external ressources in the sidebar. Some browsers might still load them even if the sidebar is hidden, but most modern browsers are intelligent enough to not load the image.

Comment: Why the hell did I get a downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery executes after the DOM is loaded. So the sidebar is loaded either way.

With CSS, you tell the browser to ignore styling the element but with jQuery you tell the browser to interact and manipulate the element, so my guess is you would actually get worse performance this way.

Comment: I guess this is the only good answer to my question. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function removeit() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
     $('body aside').remove();
    }
}
```

To fire this automatically :

```
function removeit() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
     $('body aside').remove();
    }
}
$(function() {
    removeit();
});
```

You could also add an window resize event and fire the removeIt in there (when user resizes the window or tablet/phone changes the perspective).

Comment: You need to fire the function not only to declare it, I've updated the code above and added explanation.

Comment: I know I have, but it does not remove the bar... So still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a window.resize as metioned

try-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            $('aside').remove();
        }
     });
 });
```

Comment: try it know.. i changed the code to listen to a window change

Comment: Nope, not working. Thanks anyway, I think I have to look on to other things, cause it looks like using jQuery for my problem is not the good way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

before you must place blow in head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

and js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
     $('html').find('.aside').remove(); //use class or tag name or id
    }
})
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
     $('html .aside').remove(); //use class or tag name or id
    }
})
```

Comment: you must use resize window on `$(window).resize` even try it

Comment: I don't think that's going to help, because I want this solution to be active @mobile.

Comment: answer updated and tested & worked correctly check element class/id

Comment: Worked correctly where? Not working for me. Not on mobile nor on desktop.

Comment: your first function and this work both mobile/desktop

Comment: Hmm, weird. Not working for me though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Like provided answers are suggesting, chances are that you won't get any luck with jQuery for that.

A different approach could be to make the server side *detect* whenever a visitor 
arrives on your webpage using a mobile device. That way, you could send a different version of the page depending on what your visitors are using, hence loading only the necessary DOM elements.

**What you could use with PHP**:

[php-mobile-detect (class)](https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)

Answer (score -2):

Your syntax is incorrect. Read the documentation:

[jQuery Remove DOC](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

.remove() can be called on the jQuery object that references the node to be removed and the additional option is to pass a selector to the remove method. What you're saying is remove the HTML node that has the aside selector. The code isn't doing anything because aside is not a qualifying class or ID.

$('aside').remove(optional selector); would work, using the optional selector only if the aside is given one. Not necessary unless you have multiple asides, but filtering by unique ID would be a best practice.