# Completely remove a div if screen width is less than 800 (mobile device)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i've been looking [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549451/remove-html-from-dom-if-mobile-browser-with-jquery) and i can't really find i good solution on this so i hope some of you could help me out...
I am trying to remove a div so it doesn't exist if my screen size is around the size of a mobile... I know there is display none which makes the div invisible but since i got a setInterval function on that div it stil load each 5 second... So my question is:

- Can i remove a div completely if my screen is less than x pixels
- or is it possible to only run my setinterval function when the width is more than x?

Thanks for your time!

```
    setInterval(function(){ 
$( ".chatMessages" ).load( "getMeddelanden.php" );
},5000);
```

Comment: take a look at [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a naive implementation, the setinterval runs anyway and checks if it must "operate", the div is hidden under a certain window width, you can modify this logic by clearing and restarting the interval on desidered width, inside the resize function handler, and debouncing the resize event.

```
function isMobilewidth () {
  return $(window).width() <= 800;
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.chatMessages').toggle(isMobilewidth());
});

setInterval(function(){ 
  if (!isMobilewidth())
    $( ".chatMessages" ).load( "getMeddelanden.php" );
},5000);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer worked like a charm! makes sense that i need to check if it must operate

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS media queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    div {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you want to stick with javascript, try the `.offsetWidth` property of DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

Use [CSS @media rules](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp):

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .div {
        display:none;
    }
}​
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/Luc2zrbd/

Comment: @UnknownPotato I don't like the attitude and the fact that you got not only one but two similar solutions points to your question being unclear, or at least, it could have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can get the device's screen width as shown below and do your operations accordingly.

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

you may not need a setInterval, you can base your test on a window.resize which is triggered also on page load on device mobiles
See here for an explanation of mobile viewports:

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

```
window.onresize = function(){
 // set your business here

}
```